# Debugging Play 2.3 RC1 with activator -jvm-debug and Java 8 on Windows possible?

Tags: java, playframework, typesafe-activator, playframework-2.3

I am trying to [debug play framework 2.3](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/IDE), with `activator -jvm-debug 9999 run` command, but am facing the following error:

```
E:\workspace\CustomerClub>activator -jvm-debug 9999 run
[info] Loading project definition from E:\workspace\CustomerClub\project
[info] Set current project to CustomerClub (in build file:/E:/workspace/CustomerClub/)
[warn] The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0
[error] Expected letter
[error] Expected symbol
[error] Expected '!'
[error] Expected '+'
[error] Expected '++'
[error] Expected 'debug'
[error] Expected 'info'
[error] Expected 'warn'
[error] Expected 'error'
[error] Expected ';'
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] Expected '--'
[error] Expected 'show'
[error] Expected 'all'
[error] Expected '*'
[error] Expected '{'
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected key
[error] Expected '-'
[error] 9999
[error] ^
[error] Not a valid command: jvm-debug
[error] Not a valid project ID: jvm-debug
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: jvm-debug
[error] jvm-debug
[error]          ^
```

**I am using Java 8 update 5**

Comment: This looks like an Activator bug on Windows. The best thing to do is report your issue here: https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on a Mac. Once I upgraded activator from 1.2.3 to 1.2.12 it started working.

Comment: And Activator should automatically upgrade when you run it.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably an Activator bug on Windows (see my comment). In the meantime you can manually provide debug options to the VM by setting JAVA_OPTS.

e.g. Try this:

```
> set JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999"
> activator
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Mac, so I guess it's not Windows only

Comment: Can you please report the issue? github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues. If you do, maybe you could share the link in a comment here so that people see when it is resolved. :)

Comment: It already seems to be resolved. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27483633/188947